# NullPointerException when accessing lazy loaded collection within DAO method

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate, lazy-loading

I'm having a strange issue with Spring and Hibernate when running multiple threads in an application.  I'm using spring 3.2.0.RELEASE and hibernate 4.1.12.Final.  The issue is that for some objects, when they are retrieved from the db, the retrieval succeeds, but all mapped collections are not being set.  Here's an example of my repo:

```
@Repository("fooRepository")
public class FooRepository {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FooRepository.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Foo retrieve(final Long id) {
        Foo instance = (Foo) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Foo.class, id);
        for (CollectionMember member : instance.getCollectionMembers()) {
            log.debug(member.getId());      
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

For some objects, this method always throws the following error when trying to access the CollectionMember list:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:501)
```

The problem is that the session.get() call creates PersistentBag objects for all lazy loaded collections but never sets the content.  This only occurs when multithreading is enabled.  Can anybody explain why this is happening?

EDIT:
Here's the relevant bit of the foo class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FooPK id;

    @OneToMany
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "COLLECTION_ID", referencedColumnName = "COLLECTION_ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "FOO_ID", referencedColumnName = "FOO_ID")})
    private List<CollectionMember> collectionMembers = new ArrayList<CollectionMember>();
```

And the CollectionMember class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COLLECTION_MEMBER")
@XmlRootElement(name = "collectionMember")
public class CollectionMember {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CollectionMemberPK primaryKey;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COLL_CODE")
    private CollectionCode collectionCode;
```

Comment: Providing full stack trace (even if its a bit verbose) might help troubleshoot the problem better.

Comment: any chance you can post the Foo and CollectionMember classes, or at least the bits that show mapping annotations (or the hbm.xml if you are using xml config)

Comment: I can't post the full stacktrace unless I go through and manually change a bunch of package names so you can't tell where it came from.  If you really think the full stacktrace would provide more info I'll do it, but I'm not convinced you'd need any more than you've already got in that sense, I'll add the mappings though.

Comment: If the NPE is in `toString()` does it mean that it is thrown by `log.debug(member.getId());`? If not, is it possible that this exception is thrown during a different exception is being handled? Also information about your transaction management configuration might be interesting as well - do you use `@EnableTransactionalManagement`?

Comment: Please put the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

Problem is `@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)`

This will create a returned object null instead of an empty collection in case no collection records are found. Remove and test it

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use third join table like and use Criteria for loading collection.

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "table", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "COLLECTION_ID", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "FOO_ID", nullable = true) })
    private List<CollectionMember> collectionMembers = new ArrayList<CollectionMember>();


@ManyToOne(mappedBy="collectionMembers")
private CollectionCode collectionCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does the multithreading come into play?  How are ensuring that a single thread always uses the same hibernate session?

The way I understand hibernate and lazy loading, when you traverse the collection Hibernate will look in the CurrentSession.  In a multithreaded environment that session may already have been used by another a thread.  I'm not sure if the @Transactional is enough to preserve your same Hibernate Session.

There may be a Hibernate configuration for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
Foo instance = (Foo) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Foo.class, id);

Hibernate.initialize(instance.getCollectionMembers())

for (CollectionMember member : instance.getCollectionMembers()) {

        log.debug(member.getId());      
}

return instance;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate marks all *ToMany collection mappings as lazy by default, unless stated otherwise. It's impossible for one thread to load object and not being able to read associated lazy collection inside a one @Transactional method.

What is multi-threading in your case? Do you spawn threads manually, or is it web application? How do you set session bounds?

BTW, if you really want to solve the problem, I'd advise you to post the stacktrace.. it may take just few seconds to replace you commercial package names, in case it's concern.

Answer (score 0):

When using hibernate in spring environment, it is not recommended to obtain session directly via session factory, is it may lead to session leakage. 
Try to replace with the following pattern:

```
getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            Foo instance = (Foo) session.get(Foo.class, id);
            //whatever logic goes here
            return instance;
        }
    });
```